# Выбор безопасного протокола общения с web сервером

Tags: php, c#, windows, ssl, tls

Планируется софт: программа по типу app store/play market, собственного производства.
При каждом запуске (или по желанию пользователя) она должна стучаться на наш сервер и получать информацию о доступности продуктов (приложений) обновлений новостей etc.
Так-же планируется некое подобие аккаунтов, с разными привилегиями и разным ответом (от сервера - клиенту)

Клиент - C#, windows
Сервер - IIS, windows, предпочтительно php

Какие есть варианты организовать общение между клиентом и сервером, для обмена информацией, чтоб не перехватили и не изменили содержимое/не представились сервером?

Либо на крайний случай не сложный вариант цифровой подписи сообщений с сервера (если пустить поверх HTTP)

Собственного (платного и с большим сроком) сертификата нету. letsencrypt/startssl дают на короткий срок(до 1 года). Да и в общем не понятно как через https работать (с клиента требуются сертификаты, наверное это корневые - доверенные?).

Comment: вопрос не по теме, потому что ответ очевиден, не скупитесь на сертификат ssl.

Comment: Можете сгенерировать сертификат сами, раз верить ему должен только ваш собственный клиент. [Вот детали.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33627593/2076787) Можете перевести ответ и, возможно, он поможет не только вам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте HTTPS, большего для стандартного приложения не требуется. Бесплатный сертификат делается здесь: https://www.startssl.com раз в год его перевыпускать не так сложно.

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/ ;)

Comment: После обсуждений пришли к выводу что проще всего и надёжней будет перевыпускать сертификат ежегодно, а всю "защиту" возложить на уже реализованный https.

Answer (score 0):

Даже для обычного приложения `HTTPS` по многим причинам явно маловато. ТС - советую пустить уже криптованный трафик по `HTTPS`, т.е. внутри канала все сообщения шифруются по `RSA` (для обмена ключами для `AES`) + сам `AES`. Вот этого будет достаточно, только сертификаты `RSA` - не берите непонятно откуда, генерируйте сами и не забудьте забекапить.

Comment: Назовите хотя бы пару причин (много не нужно). Ну очень интересно даже зачем обычному приложению https, не говоря о том, что его недостаточно и еще и дополнительное криптование жизненно необходимо.

Comment: @MaxZS, все просто, первая строка вопроса: "Планируется софт: программа по типу app store/play market, собственного производства." Т.е. чтобы потом ТС не рвал на голове волосы с криком: "Аааа!!! Меня поломали!!!" или "Аааа!!! Моих пользователей заразили вирусом", как было недавно с китайским AppStore.

Comment: @MaxZS, а то что посоветовали один HTTPS - "флаг вам в руки" как говорится, сами пользуйтесь. Но не вводите ТС в заблуждение о его абсолютной безопасности. На данный момент HTTPS не предоставляет нужного уровня безопасности.

Comment: И еще, от себя замечу - лучше потратить неделю на безопасную клиент-серверную связь, чем потом смотреть в глаза людям, которых из-за твоей лени протроянили криптолокерами...

Comment: С точки зрения криптографии вы предложили сделать HTTP внутри "типа-TLS" внутри TLS. Полезен в ответе только совет сделать собственные сертификаты, но без объяснения, почему.

Comment: @Align Не переводите стрелки... Вы написали `даже для обычного приложения`, так и не пишите про софт `по типу app store/play market`. Ну очень и очень далеко не все обычные приложения работают с закачкой данных и деньгами. Более того, ни протокол ни криптование ну никак не влияет на заражение вирусом. Не пишите чушь, перекидывая с больной головы на здоровую. HTTPS более чем достаточен для безопасности обычных программ. И так как все-таки насчет хотя бы пары причин, зачем дополнительное криптование обычным программам? Зачем оно вообще им может понадобиться обычным программам?

Comment: @Align И в целом, предлагаю Вам хоть образно намекнуть каким образом можно скомпрометировать HTTPS... В общих чертах...

Comment: @MaxZS, насколько мне известно все приложения "по типу app store/play market" работают с деньгами и передают конфиденциальные данные. По поводу HTTPS - почитайте что сделали с китайским AppStore и другую инфу. Если что-то не знаете - не лезьте.

Comment: @Align Вы и именно Вы в своем ответе написали "Даже для обычного приложения...". Так что не спрыгивайте на "по типу app store/play market", а ответьте мне на мой вопрос в комментарии - почему обычному приложению по многим причинам маловато https? И не ссылайтесь на темы о взломах каких-то ресурсах. Если дадите ссылку, что взлом какого-то ресурса произошел "благодаря" протоколу https, то я готов прочитать это. Ну а в остальном, то, как Вы старательно переводите стрелки, дает мне право судить, что плаваете и очень сильно именно Вы.